# Execute javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, onload

What instruction should I use so this function is executed once the page loads instead of on click?  I tried:

```
window.onload=function () {
("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
```

but the code above didn't work.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#variables").variables({
            map: ".map_canvas",
            details: "form",
            types: ["calculations", "grades"]
        });

        $("#submit_button").click(function () {

            $("#variables").trigger("calculations");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with putting it inside that last code block?

Comment: What is the `variables()` plugin that you're using?

Comment: What do you want to trigger exactly?

Comment: You second code block (with the `<script>` tag) should fire when the document is done loading due to you having `$(function() {...})`, as per jQuery's `.ready()` docs (http://api.jquery.com/ready/). Assuming `$` is jQuery at least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.onload` happens before jQuery's event `$(document).ready()` (which as you're probably aware, you've set up using the shorthand version, `$(function() {...})`).

So you're trying to trigger an event that hasn't been set up yet.

As @David pointed out, you could just put the trigger code at the end of your existing code inside `$(function() {...})`.